# function json_object_agg(text, bigint) does not exist postgres 9.2.4

Tags: postgresql

Below Query are running in the local server postgress 9.6.6 but in the server postgres 9.2.4 ,below query is not working

```
select case_type,
(obj->> 'S')::int AS single,
(obj->> 'D')::int AS division,
(obj->> 'F')::int AS full
FROM (SELECT case_type, json_object_agg(bench,disposals) AS obj
      FROM jws_ctype
      GROUP BY case_type
     )X
```

Error Below

```
ERROR:  function json_object_agg(text, bigint) does not exist
LINE 5: FROM (SELECT case_type, json_object_agg(bench,disposals) AS ...
                                ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

********** Error **********

ERROR: function json_object_agg(text, bigint) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 133
```

Comment: What's your question? That function was introduced in 9.4, why do you expect it to be available in older versions? Plus: you shouldn't be using 9.2 any more. It's no longer maintained.

Answer (score 2):

`json_object_agg` was introduced in Postgres 9.4, that is why this query will not work in Postgres 9.2